# Is OpenID Connect (OAuth2) appropriate for standard login + social login + single sign on?

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid-connect, single-sign-on

I have to implement authentication in a group of websites.

The solution will have to support standard login *(user & password)*, social login *(facebook, google+, twitter)* and single sign on *(once you are logged in to a website of the group, you are not required to log in to the other sites)*.

In addition, all these actions could be triggered through Javascript without causing page refresh (using iframes or other tricks)

Do you know if OpenID Connect is a good option? Is it overkill?
Do you known of a more appropriate option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Very interesting problem, but it might go wrong... For example, social login are only secure if you use them with a redirect. Would you want your user to input their password for facebook on your site? Personally, I would never input my facebook password unless it's on facebook site and hence require a full redirect.

Comment: @Gudradain. Well I think OpenId redirects can't be avoided but I like them to not disrupt user navigation (like Facebook login through Facebook API which shows a popup window and the parent window does not get redirected)

Comment: A popup is not enough. At the minimum, you need to have a new tab with the facebook url written at the top. What is wrong with redirecting? OpenId/OAuth security is based on the fact that the browser will redirect to the right website as specified when the (your) server registered the return URL. You remove that part and you make yourself vulnerable to all sort of phishing and man in the middle attack.

Comment: @Gudradain What if they are already logged in by facebook and the application is allowed? Must they be redirected in that case as well?

Comment: @inf3rno Yes. A redirect is always needed. BUT if the user is already logged in facebook and the application is allowed, there are no action required by the user so a double redirect happen and the user don't notice anything.

Comment: @Gudradain Is openid connect production ready? I mean wouldn't it be better to use openid2? It is hard to find relevant articles in the topic. :S